# I was installing / enableing fips 140 , rebooted as instructed now my wifi wont let me log rejecting the correct pw. Running Ubuntu Studio 20.13on

Tags: networking, ssh, encryption, security

I was attempting to make a compliant
Laptop and after enabling fips 140. I can no longer log in to my Wi-Fi networks with what were the proper passwords, it asks for password or security encryption keys. which I don't have / know where they are ... how do I get/find them? Is that even what the problem is? what am I missing?

Comment: There is no 20.13.  Which Ubuntu version are you actually working with?

Comment: Are you WiFi networks also FIPS-140 compliant? If not, connecting to them would be blocked

Comment: Turns out this is the correct answer / solution to this issue. WIFI upgrade resolved this issue. Thank you, I appreciate you assistance. Oh, correct version is 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish (x86-64)

Comment: Ok, I will move my comments into an answer

Answer (score 0):

A likely reason that you can no longer log into your WiFi networks is because those networks are not FIPS-140 compliant. FIPS-140 works by blocking unapproved ciphers and profiles, so it blocking some WiFi networks only means that FIPS-140 is working properly. Updating the WiFi networks to be FIPS-140 compliant solved the problem.